# How to change a maven goal to a quickicon in idea like the picture?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I suddenly saw a picture like this:[image]

But when I add a plugin in pom.xml the plugin did not show in idea's Plugins.[image]

How can I do this like the picture1?

Comment: Please tell which plugin did you add in pom.xml. Also will be good if you can share your pom.xml

Comment: @piy26 Just  as the picture said.I am using the Mybatis-generator plugin.I think the plguin is not important here.if you can add one plugin to the "Plugins", then any of the plguin can be put in it.